# Registers and Pointers

Tags: bit, memory-address, cpu-registers

Can you store anything but memory addresses in a register? I tried to find an answer on Google but all I found is that you CAN store pointers. This kind of implies that you can store other things, too, but how could you store a 64-bit value, for example, if a register is only 32 bits long?

Comment: For 32 bit register then 64 bit data will need to be split in two registers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Can you store anything but memory addresses in a register?

No. Registers are what CPUs nowaday actually use to operate on.

On most architectures you might know, a CPU doesn't actually care whether the content of a register is an address, or for example, an integer number for a calculation. In fact, it's common to see addresses be calculated somehow...

> how could you store a 64-bit value, for example, if a register is only 32 bits long?

Obviously, not in that register. I don't know what architecture you're referring to, but for the good ol' x86 (think: PCs) architecture, there are different registers with different lengths, and some of them may be 64 bit or longer.

Also, if you're on a CPU that actually doesn't have a register large enough for your data type, well, you'll need to load that data type into multiple registers or process it sequentially somehow.

Comment: Yes, I was referring to x86 architecture.